Mobilenet vs resnet
Q1-Why dont we remove relu after addition of skip connection in resnet50 like  we do in mobile-net v2 for better performance?
Q2-And why dont we have Convolution layer in skip connection for dimention matching of mobile-net v2 when the layer dimensions changes, like we do in resnet for matching the output channels when the layer dimensions changes?
